# who invokes Android lifecycle handlers?

Tags: android, event-driven

I am quite confused about the event-driven programming paradigm of Android? Who is in charge of invoking the lifecycle handlers (onCreate(), onResume() etc.)? Is it the Android OS? Or the Dalvik VM which runs in the application process?

Can anyone answer my question or direct me some related resources? Thank you very much.

Comment: Would it make any difference if it is the OS or the VM? It is definitely not you, that is the point. My bet is on the OS anyway.

Comment: It is main thread of the application who receives the messages "invokes" the methods. But if you want to know "who invokes" or "who triggers"?

Comment: Thanks. May I know what messages the main thread receive? I don't quite understand the difference between "invoke" and "trigger". Just want to know who calls the handlers like "onCreate()". I guess it is the Dalvik VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At OS boot, a process called the Zygote is created. This process waits for incoming requests for app startups. Once it receives a request, it forks a VM instance based on the Zygote VM itself. Thus every app is its own process with it's own sandboxed VM.
It is this VM process that starts the `onCreate()` (and other relevant methods) which subsequently start the app.

Source: My resarch on the topic.

Comment: Thanks. I have also read about Zygote. So I tend to believe that it is the Dalvik VM that invokes an activity's life cycle handlers.

Comment: Yes that's right. The Zygote is the parent process that instantiates every other process's VM.

Answer (score 0):

The activity lifecycle is a collection of methods the  `OS calls throughout the lifecycle of an activity.`

go to this Link   [Activity Lifecycle](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Activity_Lifecycle)